# I dropped out of college a decade ago. How do I finish my graduation now? [Pune, India]

Tags: graduate-school, university, withdraw, india

I was a student of Bachelor of Engineering (B.E.) - Computer Engineering, from 2007 to 2010 in Pune, India in MIT AOE - Maharashtra Institute of Technology Academy of Engineering - http://www.mitaoe.ac.in. I dropped out of college after completing 3 out of 4 years of my degree program. I had 1 backlog (Mathematics 3) when I dropped out.

Since then, I have gained 7+ years of experience in the IT industry. I have had a successful career spanning 2 mid-sized companies, each of which I served in for 3+ years. I have also achieved several high-value IT certifications in many technologies.

What is the FASTEST way for me to complete my graduation WITHOUT leaving my job. The incomplete education is holding back my career. Please guide me in this endeavor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a full fledged CS engineering degree then https://www.ieindia.org/webui/IEI-Academics.aspx#academic-programme. There seems to be some court case going on. Follow this link: https://www.facebook.com/euringbishnujee.singh/ . It's still recognised though.

Any other 3 year degree you can easily do from your local university or IGNOU.

DEB site: https://www.ugc.ac.in/deb/notices.html

The distance education bureau, DEB functions under the UGC. So trust no one else but them. They have a couple of PDFs with recognised universities. Not all universities can give distance certificate.

IGNOU: http://www.ignou.ac.in/ I've enrolled here recently.

Physically visit and interact with the staff before enrolling.

These courses will have very few classes and they're mostly on weekends. Very doable.

All the best.